# Chain animation using core animation

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, core-animation

I have several animations using CABasicAnimation, CATransition, CAKeyFrameAnimation. I want these animations to animate one after the other sequentially for different layers. i tried using CAAnimationGroup, but "CAAnimationGroup" used to provide different animation effects to the single layer.

Comment: Use the search box. The question about chaining animations has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that chaining of animation is possible by using object of NSTimer. I found this bit ambiguous process, but can be used as a work around.